# Why set the datasource in the initialWithStyle section of UIViewController doesn't work?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

It feels natural to me to set the datasource when the instance of UIViewController is being initialized

```
//LINRecipeViewController.m

#import "LINRecipeViewController.h"
#import "LINRecipeDetailViewController.h"
@interface LINRecipeViewController ()

@end

@implementation LINRecipeViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        //recipes = @[@"Panini", @"Mushroom", @"Fries"];//it doesn't working here
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    recipes = @[@"Panini", @"Mushroom", @"Fries"];//It works here


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return recipes.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = recipes[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

But it turns out that it has to be in the viewDidLoad selection. otherwise it displays a empty tableView

Could anyone explain to me why it is?

Comment: When you say "datasource" do you mean setting the `recipes" variable? It's fine to set it in `initWithStyle:`. 1) Are you sure that `initWithStyle:` is being called? 2) Are you sure `recipes` isn't being set elsewhere?

Comment: Why not doing this in `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: What do you mean "has to be"? Because it doesn't get set? Are you sure initWithStyle is called? If you are using Storyboard, the init method is initWithCoder...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by datasource in that context

Comment: @Daniel Datasource here I mean the recipes array itself, which provide the string for the Label

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal Yes I'm using storyboard,

Comment: Odds are that your `initWithStyle` is not being called, just like rmaddy said in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to have your code in viewDidLoad, but if you want it as part of the init process, put it in initWithCoder (since you are using a storyboard. initWithStyle is not called when the viewcontroller is initialized from storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Using a storyboard your - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style will not be called. You can allocate your "datasource" where (or better when) you like as long as the tableview is allocated. Calling [self.tableView reloadData] should cause the tableview to use the data.